# PHP Parsing error - unexpected '[' - PHP 5.3.29

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing the following error in PHP 5.3.29 environment

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /home/deltaweb/www/schooler/templates/yoo_master2/schooler.php on line
>   1721

The code is snippet is

```
function getUserClassPermissions()
{
  $classStr = ['I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X'];
  $classes = array();
  $user = JFactory::getUser();
  $groups = implode(',',$user->getAuthorisedGroups());
  $results = getTableData("#__usergroups", "title", "id IN ($groups)");
  foreach ($results as $row) {
    if (preg_match("/Teacher Class (\S+)/",$row[0], $matches)) {
      $classes[] = array_search($matches[1], $classStr) + 1;
    }
  }
  if (count($classes)==0) return 0;
  return implode(',',$classes);
}
```

The statement in line number 1721 is

```
$classStr = ['I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Short array syntax, `[]` is only available in PHP5.4+. You need to update your code to use the standard `array()` syntax.

OR

Update your version of PHP to one that isn't EOL.

Comment: @chandra Just read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and you'll see loads of examples.